# Magento 2 | Reindex very slow in local server

Tags: magento2, php, database, reindex, elasticsearch

On my server with:
MariaDB 10.4
PHP 7.4
Elasticsearch 7.9.1
Elasticsuite 2.10.0

I am trying to relaunch the full reindex for Magento2 but I have seen that catalog_category_product is very slow, its reindex time is 16 minutes (On my online server it is only 2 minutes).
When the reindex arrives on catalogsearch_fulltext the system is even slower and seems to never end.

The question is: How can I increase the speed of the reindex? Do I need to increase some PHP or MySQL values or is the problem due to Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Reindexing on MariaDB 10.4 takes more time compared to other MariaDB
> or MySQL versions. As a workaround, we suggest modifying the default
> MariaDB configuration and setting the following parameters:
>
> optimizer_switch='rowid_filter=off'
>
> optimizer_use_condition_selectivity = 1

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/performance-best-practices/configuration.html

Also, please refer this link for indexer optimization: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/indexer-batch.html

I hope it helps.

Comment: Good answer! But where is the file for edit this variables of MariaDB? Or how can i edit this setting? Thanks

Comment: Great man! I set the values ​​as you said and works perfectly! Thanks again :)

Comment: I'm happy to help :-)

Comment: Holy crap, those settings took my reindexing process from 2-3 days to 13 minutes! Thanks!

Comment: Big thank you for this was taking me hours to complete reindex and now 10 - 15 mins

Comment: But how and where do I need to add the variable??