# Magento 2: What is causing slow reindexing of catalogsearch_fulltext with large catalog?

Tags: magento2, reindex, mariadb

We have 400k line items, so I expect things to take a little while, but reindexing has started taking days, and often errors out in the middle. Checking in the database processlist, it looks to be stuck on a sql query:

```
+-----+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Id  | User            | Host            | db              | Command | Time  | State        | Info                                                                                                 | Progress |
+-----+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| 952 | user            | localhost:port  | db              | Query   | 67211 | Sending data | SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_prod  |    0.000 |
| 968 | user            | localhost       | db              | Query   |     0 | Init         | show processlist                                                                                     |    0.000 |
+-----+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

We are running MariaDB, and I've seen a random comment around that it takes longer for indexing than MySql, but never anything to back that up. Is it a significant difference that makes it worth switching?

Do I need to batch these updates somehow so that it doesn't hang with one massive sql query? How do folks handle indexing large catalogs?

Comment: When logged into your MariaDB and you are the MySQL Command Prompt, what is result of SELECT @@version; ?

Comment: 10.4.19-MariaDB

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;
F) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Could you post the complete query rather than just the beginning?  It should be in your Slow Query Log after you allow it to complete.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful for you to post your last 400 lines of your error.log.  Logged in as root, from MySQL Command Prompt, SELECT @@log_error; will display the error log filename.  Likewise SELECT @@slow_query_log_file; will display the Slow Query Log filename.

Comment: 24 cores, 40GB RAM. I don't have access to the error log oddly enough, will contact our host about that. Once I have that figured out I'll kick off the index again and try to get some more info. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have access to phpadmin?

Comment: Your version 10.4.19 is barely a month old.  Could it be you have an edge case of FTS indexing that has uncovered a new problem?  Your processlist posted a few days ago was still Sending Data after 67,211 seconds.  ~ 18 hours.  If you will provide additional data requested Jun 7, 21, there may be some Global Variables that could be adjusted in your configuration to improve/reduce reindexing time required.

Comment: I do have access to phpMyAdmin. I also have access to the slow query log now. Global variables are here: https://pastebin.com/Lq12muUe

Comment: Running again, currently stuck for 15 minutes on this query: https://pastebin.com/SF7yu37c

Comment: For this slow query, could you post results of EXPLAIN SELECT (your query) for analysis?  Please also post A) SHOW CREATE TABLE catalog_product_entity; B) SHOW CREATE TABLE catalog_product_website; and C) SHOW CREATE TABLE catalog_product_entity_int';  And to go with this information, A) SHOW INDEX FROM catalog_product_entity; B) SHOW INDEX FROM catalog_product_website; C) SHOW INDEX FROM catalog_product_entity_int;  for analysis of the Slow Query.  Did you forget to post from June 7 request SSD or NVME, B), D), E), F) and the 3 reports from OS Command Prompt?  Thanks

Comment: Disclaimer: I am content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile that includes FREE downloadable Utility Scripts and contact info.

Comment: EXPLAIN: https://pastebin.com/RwuRRi8P

Comment: I'm thinking I may need to switch to mysql and see if this problem goes away...

Comment: The drive is SSD, dunno about NVME. The tables and indexes are all stock Magento - haven't changed anything there. SHOW GLOBAL STATUS: https://pastebin.com/dtGXWvm2  STATUS: https://pastebin.com/9sHvFcz5  top https://pastebin.com/c1qN4cEt  ulimit https://pastebin.com/tv7Eb2dT  iostat https://pastebin.com/5Ys5KCep

Comment: Let's get a NEW Question for your Slow Query and the SHOW CREATE TABLE requests and SHOW INDEX FROM requests are important to be provided, please to allow analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section to reduce reindexing time required and generally improve speed of processing queries.

```
innodb_io_capacity=600  # from 200 to use more IOPS on your SSD devices
read_rnd_buffer_size=128K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 4,957
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=16  # from 1 to reduce mutex contention
innodb_buffer_pool_size=25G  # from 128M to reduce innodb_buffer_pool_reads RPS of 5
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function
log_slow_verbosity=query_plan,explain  # to make Slow Query Log more useful.
slow_query_log=ON  # from OFF If you could improve one query per WEEK, it would help.
```

There are many more opportunities to improve performance with your equipment.

This is ENOUGH for one Question.  The goal was one question, one answer.  Sometimes the plan does not work out.  We can separate SLOW QUERIES from SLOW REINDEXING.  Then again, everything has to work together.

Comment: @Art-Siv, In this question, you will find an answer to set 2 Global Variables to assist with reindexing - that may help AFTER applying suggestions above.  My suggestions are critical to resolving basic performance issues.  Here is URL for 2 GV suggestions. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/336813/magento-2-reindex-very-slow-in-local-server

Comment: @art-siv       Have you been able to apply Suggestions from the Answer above?  Your perspective of better/worse performance?

Comment: @art-siv       What is your situation a year later?  Thanks