# Magento 2.4.2-p1 Indexing issue

Tags: magento2, reindex

Hi We have migrated our store from **Magento 2.2.5** to **Magento 2.4.1-p1**. We are facing issues with Indexing its taking too long to complete **Category Products index** is taking 2 to 3 hours to complete. Previously in Magento 2.2.5 it was taking just 15 minutes to complete. Currently the search engine is Elastic Search [image: catalog search]

Comment: If you are using MariaDB 10.4, check this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/336816/36463

Comment: Please once try the following steps in the Magento root directory. **(1)** sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch.service **(2)** bin/magento indexer:reset **(3)** bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: @BilalUsean Thank you so much man you saved my life I owe you with my life. ;) :)  Thanks for help solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35721#issuecomment-1697207901

Verified on Magento 2.4